# How to achieve this layout using single EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

**How to acheive this type of Edit Text Using Single EditText.**
[image]

I am using this edit text in verification of otp in my app.

I am able to do this thing with 6 Edit Text like this **my_layout.xml**
is it possible to do this thing using single edit text.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To complete the installation,\nplease enter the 6-digit\nverification code."
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement TextWacher and delete each at a time for this, Your EditText looks like this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="______"
    android:inputType = "textNoSuggestions"
    android:letterSpacing="0.4" -->Its the spacing of letter
    android:textSize="29sp" />
```

And here is the implementation

```
EditText editText;
String text;
boolean delete = false;

    text = editText.getText().toString();

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            text = editText.getText().toString();
            if (count > after)
                delete = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
            int replacePosition = editText.getSelectionEnd();

            if (s.length() != 6) { //where 6 is the character underline per text
                if (!delete) {
                    if (replacePosition < s.length())
                        sb.deleteCharAt(replacePosition);
                } else {
                    sb.insert(replacePosition, '_');
                }

                if (replacePosition < s.length() || delete) {
                        editText.setText(sb.toString());
                        editText.setSelection(replacePosition);
                } else {
                        editText.setText(text);
                        editText.setSelection(replacePosition - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        delete = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working as per my requirement which i stated above

Comment: are you talking about the gap in middle ?

Comment: yes  right gap in the middle  and also  the answer you have given looks perfectly fine when there is no text inside edit text but when i starts typing it is behaving unusual

Comment: It is not a strange behaviour. Just add  `android:inputType = "textNoSuggestions"` in the editText

Comment: still the same problem persist

Comment: same mean... That underline still shows while typing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103454/discussion-between-harsh-sharma-and-shree-krishna).

Comment: @HarshSharma bro, have you implemented this, Is there any issue that I need to update here..

Comment: i will tell you is it working or not in a hour or you have to do some changes if any problem come  i wil tell you

Comment: thanks alot bro for this answer(and your hard work) and now it is working fine  but i want it to be working on api 14 how it can be done. Right now it is working perfectly from api 16 as letterspacing is introduced in api 16 is there any workaround for api below 16

Comment: I am really sorry for this bro, I tried but couldn't achieve this. It was only for greater API level then 21. I've recently asked this question in stack overflow But it was marked as duplicate question but it isn't, I have proved that by editing the question, Please vote to re-open the question, so that we can get help...

Answer (score -1):

I think its too late, but once you'll get time you should try this one. I hope this will fulfill your requirement.

pincode_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_first_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_second_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_third_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_forth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_fifth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/pin_sixth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otp_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/otp_edittext_style" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText android:id="@+id/pin_hidden_edittext"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:textColor="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/pin_content_desc" />
```

PinCodeLayout.java

```
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;

 import com.elanic.R;
 import com.elanic.utils.StringUtils;

/**
  * Created by sandeep on 8/19/2017.
*/

public class PinCodeLayout extends LinearLayout implements 
View.OnFocusChangeListener, View.OnKeyListener, TextWatcher {
private EditText mPinFirstDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinSecondDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinThirdDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinForthDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinFifthDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinSixthDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinHiddenEditText;
private boolean isManuallyEntering = true;
private String pinCodeText;
private PinCodeCallBack pinCodeCallback;


public PinCodeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public PinCodeLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

 public PinCodeLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int 
    defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
 }

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
  after) {

}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.pin_first_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_second_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_third_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_forth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.pin_fifth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.pin_sixth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
 }

@Override
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.pin_hidden_edittext:
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                    if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 6)
                        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 5)
                        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 4)
                        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 3)
                        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText("");
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 2)
                        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText("");
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 1)
                        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText("");

                    if (mPinHiddenEditText.length() > 0) {

             mPinHiddenEditText.setText(mPinHiddenEditText.getText()
              .subSequence(0, mPinHiddenEditText.length() - 1));
                        mPinHiddenEditText.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                          mPinHiddenEditText.setSelection(mPinHiddenEditText.
                             getText().toString().length());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            case R.id.pin_first_edittext:
            case R.id.pin_second_edittext:
            case R.id.pin_third_edittext:
            case R.id.pin_forth_edittext:
            case R.id.pin_fifth_edittext:
            case R.id.pin_sixth_edittext:
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 || keyCode == 
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 ||
                        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 || keyCode == 
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3 ||
                        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4 || keyCode == 
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5 ||
                        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6 || keyCode == 
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7 ||
                        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8 || keyCode == 
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) {
                    isManuallyEntering = true;
                }
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinFirstDigitEditText);
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinSecondDigitEditText);
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinThirdDigitEditText);
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinForthDigitEditText);
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinFifthDigitEditText);
    setDefaultPinBackground(mPinSixthDigitEditText);


    if (s.length() == 0) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinFirstDigitEditText);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText("");
        pinCodeText = "";
    } else if (s.length() == 1) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinSecondDigitEditText);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(0) + "");
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");
    } else if (s.length() == 2) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinThirdDigitEditText);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(1) + "");
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");

    } else if (s.length() == 3) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinForthDigitEditText);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(2) + "");
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");

    } else if (s.length() == 4) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinFifthDigitEditText);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(3) + "");
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");

    } else if (s.length() == 5) {
        setFocusedPinBackground(mPinSixthDigitEditText);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(4) + "");
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");

    } else if (s.length() == 6) {
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText(s.charAt(5) + "");
        setDefaultPinBackground(mPinSixthDigitEditText);
        pinCodeText = s.toString();
        hideSoftKeyboard(mPinSixthDigitEditText);
        if (isManuallyEntering) {
            pinCodeCallback.onPinCodeEntered();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}


private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.pincode_layout, this);
    init();
    setPINListeners();
}

/**
 * Initialize EditText fields.
 */
private void init() {
    mPinFirstDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_first_edittext);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_second_edittext);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_third_edittext);
    mPinForthDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_forth_edittext);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_fifth_edittext);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.pin_sixth_edittext);
    mPinHiddenEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext);
    isManuallyEntering = true;
}

private void setPINListeners() {
    mPinHiddenEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

    mPinFirstDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinForthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    mPinFirstDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinForthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinHiddenEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    Log.d("TAG", "proposed: " + proposedHeight + ", actual: " + 
    actualHeight);

    if (actualHeight >= proposedHeight) {
        // Keyboard is shown
        if (mPinHiddenEditText.length() == 0)
            setFocusedPinBackground(mPinFirstDigitEditText);
        else
            setDefaultPinBackground(mPinFirstDigitEditText);
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

/**
 * Sets default PIN background.
 *
 * @param editText edit text to change
 */
private void setDefaultPinBackground(EditText editText) {
    setViewBackground(editText, 
  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.otp_drawable));
}

/**
 * Sets focus on a specific EditText field.
 *
 * @param editText EditText to set focus on
 */
public static void setFocus(EditText editText) {
    if (editText == null)
        return;

    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
}

/**
 * Sets focused PIN field background.
 *
 * @param editText edit text to change
 */
private void setFocusedPinBackground(EditText editText) {
    setViewBackground(editText, 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.otp_drawable));
}

/**
 * Sets background of the view.
 * This method varies in implementation depending on Android SDK version.
 *
 * @param view       View to which set background
 * @param background Background to set to view
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setViewBackground(View view, Drawable background) {
    if (view == null || background == null)
        return;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackground(background);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param editText EditText which has focus
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    if (editText == null)
        return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    getContext().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
    if (pinCodeCallback != null) {
        //  pinCodeCallback.hideProgressBar(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Hides soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param editText EditText which has focus
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    if (editText == null)
        return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    getContext().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    if (pinCodeCallback != null) {
        // pinCodeCallback.hideProgressBar(true);
    }
}

public void setData(CharSequence data) {

    if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(data)) {
        isManuallyEntering = false;
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(0)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(0)));
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(1)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.append(String.valueOf(data.charAt(1)));
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(2)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.append(String.valueOf(data.charAt(2)));
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(3)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.append(String.valueOf(data.charAt(3)));
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(4)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.append(String.valueOf(data.charAt(4)));
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText(String.valueOf(data.charAt(5)));
        mPinHiddenEditText.append(String.valueOf(data.charAt(5)));

        hideSoftKeyboard(mPinSixthDigitEditText);
        if (pinCodeCallback != null) {
            pinCodeCallback.onPinCodeEntered();
        }
    } else {
        isManuallyEntering = true;
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText("");
        mPinHiddenEditText.setText("");
        setFocus(mPinFirstDigitEditText);
        showSoftKeyboard(mPinFirstDigitEditText);

    }

}

public String getPinCodeText() {
    return pinCodeText;
}

public void setCallBack(PinCodeCallBack pinCodeCallBack) {
    this.pinCodeCallback = pinCodeCallBack;
}

public interface PinCodeCallBack {

    void onPinCodeEntered();

    /**
     * true --> show && false--> hide
     **/
    void hideProgressBar(boolean show);
}
}
```

otp_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">
<corners android:radius="1dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/otpBackgroundColor" />
```

edittext style

```
 <style name="otp_edittext_style">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:cursorVisible">false</item>
    <item name="android:maxLength">1</item>
    <item name="android:minEms">2</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/post_description_color</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
</style>
```